# Why are these topologies not comparable?

Tags: general-topology

These topologies are on $\Bbb R$. The finite complement topology (T3) and the topology having the sets $(-\infty, a)=\lbrace x\,|\,x \lt a\rbrace$ as basis (T5).

I'm very confused because some papers say to

> consider point $1$ and two open sets $\Bbb R − \lbrace 0\rbrace \in$ T3 and $(−\infty,2) ∈$ T5 containing it. Neither of these open sets contains an open set from the other topology that contains $1$.

My question is: isn't $\Bbb R - \lbrace 0\rbrace$ not in the finite complement topology since $\Bbb R$ is infinite, and if you get rid of one point, you still have an infinite set?

Comment: $\Bbb R-\{0\}$ _is_ an open set in the co-finte topology, because its complement is $\{0\}$, a finite set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$O = \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ *is* in $T_3$, because its complement, $\{0\}$, is finite. $1 \in O$, but if we would have $(-\infty, a) \in T_5$ with with $1 \in (-\infty, a)\subseteq O$ then $a >1$ and so $0 \in (-\infty, a)$ as well ,so $(-\infty, a) \nsubseteq O$. So $1$ is not an interior point of $O$ in $T_5$, so $O \notin T_5$.
So $O \in T_3, O \notin T_5$.

On the other hand, $O' = (-\infty, 2) \in T_5$. Then $1 \in O'$ but if $1 \in \mathbb{R}\setminus F \subseteq O'$, we'd have $X \setminus O' = [2, \rightarrow) \subseteq \mathbb{R} \setminus O = F$, which is a contradiction,as the former is infinite, and $F$ is finite by definition of $T_3$. So $1$ is not an interior point of $O'$ in $T_3$, so $O' \notin T_3$.

So $O' \in T_5, O' \notin T_3$. So $T_3$ and $T_5$ are not comparable.